# How does one subscribe to BattleField 3 Premium Events?

Tags: battlefield-3

Looking at the [news page](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/news/view/2832654787059404831/) on battlelog, I noticed this weekend friends @Battlefield will be spawning an Air Kills competition, which turns out to be very interesting (I think I have no chances, btw :).

Anyways, I can't clearly understand if one has to subscribe to the event somewhere or it just suffice to play BF3 to join.

Does someone already know how such BF3 events work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Battlefield 3 Premium Event. That means to part take in the event you need to be a Premium Member.

This is from the Battlefield 3 Premium on Battlelog:

> Join our Premium exclusive competition to see who can get the most
>   kills from the air in Armored Kill! If you are one of the top 5
>   players on your format during these 48 hours, you will receive a
>   limited edition, signed and numbered lithograph featuring artwork from
>   Battlefield 3. To join this competition, you need to log in to our
>   Premium exclusive competition servers we have set up. You also need to
>   supply a password to enter any of the servers. By entering the
>   password, you confirm that you have read and agreed to the terms and
>   conditions for this competition. Competition details, terms and
>   conditions, and password will be published in the News section here on
>   Battlelog.